# screen as an intransitive verb?

Tags: transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

Most dictionaries list the verb **screen** in the sense of showing a movie as a transitive verb, but I have seen the following sentence:

48 hours of movies will **screen** in the movie theater.

Do you think "screen" is used correctly here?

Comment: How else would you have it expressed?

Comment: Many English verbs exhibit behave like this, acting sometimes as transitive verbs with Agent subjects and Patient objects and at other times as  intransitive verbs with Patient subjects. A classic pair is *She is boiling eggs . . . Eggs are boiling*. There are many terms for such verbs and behaviors: unaccusative, ergative, labile, middle voice. Here are some questions which may be helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17089, https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/43018, 
https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/130169

Comment: It's very common to shorten a phrase like "be screened" to just "screen".

Comment: Am I right in thinking It's much more common to shorten a phrase like *be screened* to *screen* alone in US American than my British English?